# How to play an audio from url in a app widget

Tags: android

Im implementing app widget to play audio from url,

I used mediaplayer class to play audio when click on a play button in widget.

but im not getting audio output, 
is there any way to work out on this issue.

Please let me know, or give me a reference to follow

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will help you to play audio from URL.

```
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.reset();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("http:\\your url\test.mp3"));
                mp.setLooping(false); // Set looping
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```